# An app deployed to Heroku can't access to MySQL database in cPanel remotely

Tags: python, mysql, heroku, deployment, cpanel

i am deploying a python app to Heroku, an there is an error when accessing the app after deployment,

```
 (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server
```

obviously it is about my login system which is using MySQL to store the usernames and passwords.

Now this database sits in my cPanel, and i have already set the Remote MySQL Access hosts to a wild card "%" (trying to allow all incoming request from all ips to this database).

[image]

But now it seems this app on Heroku can't access to this database. Any solution for that?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if it helps create a php database query [api script](https://medium.com/@shashanksrivastava/create-a-rest-api-using-php-mysql-60ba1ad918d2) on your server that hosts the database and access it from your python code on heroku with [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/) package.